# Why would setting the Application.EnableEvents property cause "Run-time error '50290': Expecting object to be local"?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Recently I've had an issue with setting the `Application.EnableEvents` property in an event handler of a custom Application class module. In this particular case, it happens when `xlXExcelApplication_WorkbookBeforeSave` is triggered by a save event (`xlXExcelApplication` being the name of my custom class).

When I attempt to set the property to FALSE with the statement, `Application.EnableEvents = False`, I'm expecting that the application's events are disabled and the code simply moves on to the next line. Instead, an error occurs: "Run-time error '50290' Expecting object to be local."

Usually I get the "Expecting object to be local" error when I try to access an Excel object by passing an argument to a collection that I expect will identify and return that collection object, i.e. `Worksheets("My_Worksheet")` or `Range("My_Range")`, where neither "My_Worksheet" or "My_Range" are valid worksheet names/range names. However, `Application` is a global object that always exists so I can't see how this error would apply to the `Application` object.

I tried setting the property from the Immediate window and tried using the fully qualified reference, `Excel.Application = False`, but both of these attempts also returned the same error message. However, *getting* the `EnableEvents` property from the `Application` object does NOT cause an error. And once the procedure runs and I try setting the `Application.EnableEvents` property to True or False in the Immediate window afterwards, I have no problem. I also have numerous other procedures that set the `Application.EnableEvents` property with no issue in those instances.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this problem?

Comment: If I understand you correctly **(Please do correct me if I am wrong. Or better include the relevant blocks of code in the above post)**, try creating a property using `LET/GET` within the class module to handle the event disabling. For example in the class module, `Private ClsEnableEvents As Boolean` and then `Property Let EnableEvents(value As Boolean)` and `Property Get EnableEvents() As Boolean` procs. Finally in a normal module, using `xlXExcelApplicationInstance.EnableEvents = False` or `xlXExcelApplicationInstance.EnableEvents = True`?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I actually already had a method for my custom class called "EnableAppEvents" but I rarely use it because it's just as easier just to call the built-in "EnableEvents" method of the Application object. 

But since I posted the original message I haven't had any problems with any of the code statements that include the line Application.EnableEvents. I have no idea what's changed but fingers crossed that it stays this way. Of course, there are myriad of other issues that have come up in the meantime, but that's for another post.